# How many good choices are there in this card problem?

Tags: probability

> You have a deck of
> n
> cards with face values
> 1
> ,
> …
> ,
> n
> , out with you pick
> m
> cards u.a.r. without replacement. You want to know what is the probability that there are at least
> m −
> 1
> cards whose face values are consecutive among the
> m
> that you picked. We have $4\leq n \leq 20$ and $4\leq m \leq n$

I solved this problem a while ago, but I can't remember why my solution works. So I thought we count the good choices and divide by the number of total possible choices. The total possible choices are $n \choose m$, this makes sense. However for the good choices back then I found that there are $(n-m+1)^2$ many. Why? I can't remember why this makes sense.

Comment: If $m=2$ then the probability is $1$.  However your formula would appear to  give  $(n-2+1)^2\big /\binom n2$ which is not $1$.

Comment: Unless I am missing something (always possible) there's just some case work to do.  It's easy to count the cases with $m$ consecutive cards.  To count those with exactly $m-1$ you need to isolate the cases where the streak starts at $1$ or ends at $n$.  A little tedious, but not really hard.

Comment: I forgot to mention the restrictions, sorry

Comment: @lulu yeah, but with my formula we can skip the tedious part of counting. My formula definitely works, this was a coding exercise with rigorous testing - and my formula passed all the tests

Comment: But you have to demonstrate that the formula works.  The counting method I described shouldn't take very long (though it would appear to be a little error prone).

Comment: @lulu I didn't ask for a solution for this problem - I asked for an explanation for my solution. If I could demonstrate that my solution works, I would have to understand it first myself, but I don't understand it - hence my question. But with my restrictions added, you could easily falsify my formula with another counterexample if you are in doubt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are $n-m+2$ ways to pick a run of length $m-1$. For each of these we can pick the remaining card in $n-m+1$ ways. This gives a total of $$(n-m+2)(n-m+1).$$

However each of the $n-m+1$ cases where we have a run of $m$ cards has been counted twice in this process so we must subtract $n-m+1$ giving
$$(n-m+1)^2.$$

Comment: Where have you used $m>2$?

Comment: This makes sense, thank you!

Comment: @Henry. When $m=2$  the remaining card is a run of length $m-1$  in its own right and so  there is more double counting in that case.

Comment: I have updated the question - we have $m>2$

Comment: Yes, thanks - I had noticed that.